# String not shows proper value when convert CharCode to string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When i try to convert CharCode to string its shows value like below attach

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing the part of your code for better understanding?

Comment: @FredericChang Thanks for comment i use this code String.fromCharCode(8533) for convert

Comment: @FredericChang Thanks for your answer. I tried in IOS device and its working fine but in a android device its not convert.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from Flutter not from Dart.
As you can see from the attached photo, the console could show it properly "⅕".
However, when I feed it to Text Widget, it will show as same as you tested.

I've posted this question on [Flutter GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/108103).

[image]
[image]